# Why do we say "Ve'Atah Kadosh"?

Tags: tefilla

Why do we say "Ve'atah Kadosh" on

1. Motzei Shabbos (after Shabbos).
2. After reading the Megilla.
3. After reading Eicha?

What is so special about these days?

**EDIT**

And what connection does this have to do with the prayer of "Ve'atah Kadosh"?

Moreover, why do we skip the first phrase of Uva Letzion?

Comment: They're the only time the maariv service has an extra component post shemone esrei.

Comment: @DoubleAA, Except for Simchas Torah.

Comment: @DoubleAA What about V'Yichulu on Shabbos?  While it is technically a repetition of Shoma Esre, it is still an extra component.

Comment: As for skipping Uva letzion: its cuz we dont mention גאולה (redemption) at night (Mishnah Berura 295:2). That might also covers tisha be'av (we dont over-mention geulah on that day)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regarding **Motzei Shabbos** (after Shabbos) the Kitzur Shulchan Aruch in 96:2 explains:

אחר כך אומרים ואתה קדוש וגו' וסדר קדושה ששייך לויהי נועם, שעל ידי מלאכת המשכן שרתה שכינה בישראל, וזהו ואתה קדוש יושב תהלות ישראל, אם חל יום טוב בשבוע הבא אפילו בערב שבת אין אומרים ויהי נועם ואתה קדוש, דכיון שאומרים בויהי נועם ומעשה ידינו כוננהו, צריך שיהיו כל ששת ימים ראוי למלאכה, וכיון שאין לומר ויהי נועם, גם ואתה קדוש אין אומרים דשייכי להדדי.

---

Regarding **Purim after reading the Megilla** the Kitzur Shulchan Aruch writes in 414:4:

ואתה קדוש (שהוא במזמור למנצח על אילת השחר, שנאמר על אסתר ושם נאמר אלהי אקרא וגו' דנאמר על מקרא מגילה, דאמר ר' יהושע בן לוי, חייב אדם לקרות את המגילה בלילה ולשנותה ביום, שנאמר אלהי אקרא יומם ולא תענה, ולילה ולא דומיה לי, וסמיך ליה ואתה קדוש וגו'),

---

He does not explain why we say **after reading Eicha**.

---

*I'll try translate this later.*